# Changing polar coordinates: Calculating $\iint_R\frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I'm studying in preparation for a Mathematical Analysis II examination and I'm solving past exam exercises.
*If it's any indicator of difficulty, the exercise is Exercise 4 of 4, part $d$ and graded for 10%.*

> Calculate the integral $$\iint_R\dfrac{dxdy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$ (by changing polar coordinates) where $R=\left\{(x,y):1\leq x^2+y^2\leq 2, x\leq0, y\geq0\right\}$.

I was able to come to an answer, but I'm not sure about its correctness.
I started by noting that the given $R$ is a part of a *circular ring* with centre O and area of the circle with centre O and radius 2 **minus** the circle with centre O and radius 1.

I was then able to substitute $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, and make some assumptions based on the thought above:
By replacing the substitutes of x and y in $1\leq x^2 + y^2\leq 2 \Rightarrow 1\leq r^2(\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta)\leq 2 \Rightarrow 1\leq r \leq \sqrt{2}$.
Additionally, based on the $x\leq 0, y\geq 0$ from the exercise itself (and the visualisation of the top-left half of the circular ring that is $R$), we've got that $\dfrac{\pi}{2}\leq\theta\leq\pi$.

With these two assumptions in mind, I move on and calculate the integral as follows:
$$\iint_R\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dx dy = \int^{\pi}_{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int^{\sqrt{2}}_1\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{r^2\cos^2\theta + r^2\sin^2\theta }}rdrd\theta = \int^{\pi}_{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int^{\sqrt{2}}_1 (\dfrac{1}{r})rdrd\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} (\sqrt{2} - 1 ) $$

Does my answer look correct? I feel I made bad assumptions, or too many and a mistake in my process leads to the weird result. Like I missed crucial steps.
In any case, any validation or help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: your soln is correct except the end point of $\theta$ It should be $0< \theta< \pi$

Comment: by the way, question says $x<=2$ does't it?

Comment: If the limit for x is correct, then it doesn't do anything at all - the entire annulus of integration lies within it. So y condition cuts the annulus in half, but x doesn't cut further.... unless it's x<=0, in which case your answer is correct. But that's limits - inside the integrand, you did well.

Comment: @orion sorry, x<=0, you are correct. Mistyped there.

Comment: @candy_corcia check the above comment, I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By rotational symmetry, one can also compute $1/4$ of the integral over the whole angle $2\pi$: since $dx\,dy=r\,dr\,d\varphi$,
$$
\int_{R} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}d(x,y) = \frac{1}{4}\int_{1<r<\sqrt 2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}d(x,y)=\frac{2\pi}{4}\int_1^{\sqrt{2}}dr=\frac{\pi}{2}(\sqrt{2}-1).
$$
But it is pretty much the same as you did; it was just to remind that symmetry in some cases can be a powerful ally.

Answer (score 1):

Integrand is $1/r$  Area with Jacobian $ \frac12 \int r^2/r  \cdot  d\theta $... ;$ \theta$ limits $ \pi/2 .. \pi, $ ; $r$ limits $ 1 .. \sqrt 2. $ All ok